# pagination in php recent row first

Tags: php, pagination

I've created different pages for 20 different rows in my php code, please have a look-

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page = $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $page = '';
}

if($page=='' || $page==1)
{
    $page1=0;
}
else
{
    $page1=($page*20)-20;
}

$query="SELECT * FROM issued_books limit $page1,20";
if($did_query_exec=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
 while($query_exec=mysqli_fetch_array($did_query_exec, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
   $isret = $query_exec["Date_returned"];
   $dateret = $query_exec["Date_returned"];
   $dateis = $query_exec['Date_issued'];
   //echoing the values here
 }
}
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `issued_books`";
     $Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     $cou = mysqli_num_rows($Result);
     $a = $cou/20;
     echo "</br></br>";
     $a = ceil($a);

     echo  'Page&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
     for($b=$a; $b>=1; $b--)
     {
         echo "<a href='return-books.php?page=$b' style='text-decoration:none'>$b&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
     }
```

The above code creates the link for all the pages with row 1 of page 1 contains the first record inserted by me.

I wish to display the recent most created record in row 1 of page 1

any kinda help would be really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: you can fetch the data with `DESC` order

Comment: `$query="SELECT * FROM issued_books  ORDER BY id DESC limit $page1,20";`  And `$query = "SELECT * FROM issued_books ORDER BY id DESC";`

Comment: I know @Alive_to_Die, I didn't  run the code by that time, just have now, thanks for the help

Comment: @ParvezKhan  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `ORDER BY` with `DESC`:-

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `issued_books` ORDER BY id DESC limit $page1,20";
```

And

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `issued_books` ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Note:- change the column name in `ORDER BY` according to your wish.